# UV Unwrapping face problem

Tags: uv

I'm trying to UV unwrap a face just as a test.

[image]

But I'm getting a strange UV result where only one side of the face is unwrapped.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. you need to add more details, like how does your mesh looks

Comment: take  a look again

Comment: From your images, you are cutting the Head in two with the Seams (Red Lines), you need to put the seams only in the places that you need to cut. Also make sure that you dont have a mirror modifier

Comment: i dont get it, i cut in the same areas that  i saw in my course and others videos out there, ii did this mesh with retopoflow simetry

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: i removed the mirror modifier and get just half of the model, what now?

Comment: You are not supposed to remove it, but apply it, then select your faces again and unwrap again Like [HERE](https://youtu.be/mmYJWMP_M4E?t=965)

Comment: im tired of this program man just giving up for know